# Can an ASP.NET page be a WebService also?

Tags: asp.net

I know it's a little odd, specifically because a Page inherits from the System.Web.Page (or something) and a WebService inherits from System.Web.Service (or something).

But just thought I'd ask if there is any way to do this? Does anyone have suggestions to do this?

```
public class MyWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public String MyMethod()
    {
        return "";
    }
}

public class MyWebPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void ExecuteButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to have an aspx page act like a web service?

Comment: I have a need. We have a ASP.NET page that has legacy code, we want to expose it through a web service, we'd love to go do the "right thing". We're in a time crunch.

Comment: though you can make this static and call it from the webservice directly by referring it by pagename why not add this method to one of the existing services and call it from there.

Comment: Ok the code I posted doesn't work, I wonder why.

Comment: Can you give an example of the SOAP message? What will the SOAPAction be? etc. As someone commented, there is no way to get the WSDL

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are looking for but you can have [WebMethod] as an attribute to your method on .aspx.cs page. I use it to execute this method from .aspx page.

ex:-

```
 [WebMethod]
public static void YourMethod(string parameter)
{    

}
```

From the code that you have posted thing I cannot see the static method on your page secondly I dont see the call in your service to the method. 
try doing something like this

```
public static type MyMethodOnPage()
```

and the in your servie method call this static method.

```
public type MyMethodInService()
{
    return MyPageName.MyMethodOnPage();
}
```

Comment: ok, can I make web service calls to this aspx page that has codebehind like that?

Comment: you can use PageName.MethodName() since this is static method.

Comment: What benefit does this have? If you don't inherit from WebService it won't generate wsdl etc.  What does this WebMethod attribute by itself add?

Comment: I have mentioned that I use to call this from aspx and this is called AJAX callbacks. I hope that AJAX callbacks makes some sense for you. Anyways Michael thank you for coming up with your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we have. We can use AJAX callbacks.

Check this URL

**[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200803212711/http://geekswithblogs.net/frankw/archive/2008/03/13/asp.net-ajax-callbacks-to-web-methods-in-aspx-pages.aspx)**

Comment: ok, that does help somewhat. But let me update the question with what I really want.

Comment: You mean to say, you want to access the aspx page as web service and wanted to use in another application?
In that case, without WSDL how it will work?